# Creating an Drop Pin MKPinAnnotation supporting dragging like the Drop Pin in Maps App

Tags: iphone, drag-and-drop, mkmapview, mkannotation

I wonder if it's possible to create an MKPinAnnotation in a Custom MKMapView, which answers to touch and drag just like the "Drop Pin" annotation in the Maps App.

I would like a way to drop a pin at a location given by the GPS. Then let the user fine tune the exact location by touching the Pin and dragging it right, if the GPS is a bit too inaccurate.

Any help is appreciated, or information if this is impossible with allowed SDKs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can check out my project: http://github.com/digdog/MapKitDragAndDrop, it runs on OS 3.1 or later.

Comment: this is now a dead link

Answer (score 4):

This may help too, if you just want to see how to do it with 4.0: [(iPhone) how to implement draggable pins using OS 4.0 MapKit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191728/iphone-how-to-implement-draggable-pins-using-os-4-0-mapkit)