# (iPhone) how to implement draggable pins using OS 4.0 MapKit?

Tags: iphone, mapkit, draggable, mkmapview, drag

Can anyone provide any sample code/instructions for implementing draggable pins in OS 4.0 using the MapKit framework?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sure thing buddy (yes I'm talking to myself),

In your custom annotation add:

```
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
```

This satisfies the requirement of implementing setCoordinate, as mentioned inhttp://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotationView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MKAnnotationView/draggable

In your MapView delegate add:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)annotationView didChangeDragState:(MKAnnotationViewDragState)newState fromOldState:(MKAnnotationViewDragState)oldState 
{
//..Whatever you want to happen when the dragging starts or stops
}
```

and in your AnnotationView set draggable to true, so for example:

```
customAnnotationView.draggable      = YES;
```

I think that was everything that I did to get it working. Tell me if you have troubles.

Comment: I'm using the custom annotation class "MapLocation" from the book "More iPhone Development" - it's a normal custom annotation class. I added ,assign to the existing property to make it like above, but the drag callback is never invoked. In viewForAnnotation I cast the annotation as a MapLocation and fetched its view and set draggable=YES.

I did it just for testing, I will probably go with OS3 support. But do you have an idea what could be missing?

Comment: Tristan would you be willing to share the code you used to get it woking? I am doing everything I can think of but for some reason I cannot get the pin to move and I have tried every tutorial out there I could find (including the comment below). Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Check out [MapKitDragAndDrop](http://github.com/digdog/MapKitDragAndDrop) by Ching-Lang Huang and the author's accompanying [blog post](http://digdog.tumblr.com/post/744530746/mapkitdraganddrop-3).